# Is there any fl.control.* classes that exist in Flex AS3?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

The internet says to add

```
import fl.controls.Combobox
```

But Flex says that there is no class called fl.controls

Which is the equivalent class in flex?

Comment: Check out Tour de Flex, to see what Flex components you need-- http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/tourdeflex/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot import `fl.*` classes to a Flex application, and you cannot import `mx.*` classes to a Flash application - those are platform specific if you will. Only `flash.*` classes can be used irrespective of the platform.

Use the flex combo box as already suggested, or export the flash combo box to an SWC and give it a shot.

This shouldn't be an issue if you're using Flex as just an editor - that is if you're not compiling your AS files using Flex. The only problem would be that you won't get auto-complete for `fl` classes. You can just ignore the flex errors and compile it using flash.

Comment: thanks for that , i started using flash now , flex is very bad

Comment: @Mirage Flex is good for data driven user interfaces, while flash is good for animations. You've to choose the right platform.

Answer (score 1):

[mx.controls.ComboBox](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/ComboBox.html)

Comment: but i am creating a flash application , can't i use same class .
i can use that in flash . i just want to use flex as editor

Comment: ok, well you asked what the equivalent class was in flex. you need to add the fl.* classes as a compiled .swc to your project. http://evolve.reintroducing.com/2007/10/30/tips-n-tricks/fl-package-swc/